# Get information about installed apps on my Android

Tags: android, browser, get, device

i need to get data about all installed apps on my Android device.

For example I need that my app is able to get information like active sessions from the browser, or how many mail was sent from the device or received packets.

It seems very hard but I think that it will be a solution!

Comment: even if that is possible, it is certainly not recommended... please mention what is your actual requirement in detail...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().
    queryIntentActivities(mIntent, 0);
```

This will get you the list of installed apps having intent

```
Intent.ACTION_MAIN
```

I think the browser part is not easy. You will have to keep a track of when browser was started and keep a continous watch if its still running. And mail part is I guess doable but have no idea about it.